# Discord.py if not working to check boolean

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Here's my little problem:

```
        if start == False:
          start = True
          players_list.append(ctx.message.author.id)
          await self.client.send_message(channel, '**Session created by {}** Wait another player to join..'.format(ctx.message.author))
```

start boolean in that if caused an error bcs I put `start = True` inside that if

Entire code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

players_list = []
wolves_list = []
villagers_list = []

start = False

class Werewolf:

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.command(pass_context = True)
    async def playww(self, ctx):
        channel = ctx.message.channel
        if start == False:
            start = True
            players_list.append(ctx.message.author.id)
            await self.client.send_message(channel, '**Session created by {}** Wait another player to join..'.format(ctx.message.author))
        else:
            await self.client.send_message(channel, '**Session already created!**')

    @commands.command(pass_context = True)
    async def joinww(self, ctx):
        channel = ctx.message.channel
        id_player = ctx.message.author.id
        if start == True:
            if id_player not in players_list:
                players_list.append(id_player)
                await self.client.send_message(channel, '**{}** joined the game!'.format(ctx.message.author))
            else:
                await self.client.send_message(channel, '**{}** already inside player list!'.format(ctx.message.author))
        else:
            await self.client.send_message(channel, 'Create session first by `-playww` command!')


def setup(client):
        client.add_cog(Werewolf(client))
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `start` (and all of the other "global" variables) an attribute of the `Werewolf` cog.

```
class Werewolf:

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client
        self.players_list = []
        self.wolves_list = []
        self.villagers_list = []
        self.start = False
```